Packing a sqlite database in .net maui
What I want to do is include an SQLite database when a user installs the app. user will not update/delete from it just to look up information.
I am trying to do this How to pack existing sqlite database on my .net maui app. I found an way here.
How to pack existing SQLite Database in MAUI app
I could not comment on this question so that is why i ask this.
I understand that i need to copy the database to the resources/raw folder.
In a database class i have this from a sample
using SQLite;
using TodoSQLite.Models;

namespace TodoSQLite.Data;

public class TodoItemDatabase
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;
    public TodoItemDatabase()
    {
    }
    async Task Init()
    {
        if (Database is not null)
            return;

        Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
        var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>();
    }

Where do i put this code. And do i change aboutassets.txt to the database name.
async Task LoadMauiAsset()
    {
        using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("AboutAssets.txt");
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }


you would generally put this code into the app startup.  And you can name the file when you add it to the assets folder

Your code is creating the db. So as such you don't have to pack it along with the app. You would directly create the db at a writeable location. The assets/resources folders are only for readonly content.
You can pack it under the assets folder and mark it the resource as MauiAsset. Then you can copy the file from assets folder to the folder where the app can write to the db.
You would write the db into the app's data folder location or any other location meant for creating app files.
Like you would get the folder location where you can create the db file as shown below:
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)

